# JavaScript remove elements from array until x

Tags: javascript, arrays

I gather an array of times from my back-end `[09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30]...` and I would like to filter all times out before and including 12:00.

How would I go about?

I have thought about using an `$.each` on the array and checking the strings against each other, but I am not sure if that is the right approach.

Comment: Are these times orderer?

Comment: Yes, they are ordered

Comment: What format do your times have? The notation you provided is not valid javascript. If it is in strings, then format would be `["09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30"]`. In that case @VisioN's first answer would work and has my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the only answer so far that will filter out times if `12:00` is not present in the array:

```
var array = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00'];

var result = array.filter(function(e) {
    var date = new Date('1.1.2000 ' + e),  // create Date object
        hours = date.getHours();           // get hours from time

    return hours > 12 || (hours === 12 && date.getMinutes() > 0);
});

console.log( result );  // ["12:30", "13:00"]
```

Alternatively, without relying on `Date` object, we can use simple string manipulation:

```
var result = array.filter(function(e) {
    var date = e.split(':'),  // split time by ':'
        hours = +date[0];     // get hours as a number

    return hours > 12 || (hours === 12 && +date[1] > 0);
});

console.log( result );  // ["12:30", "13:00"]
```

Another even more straightforward solution is to transform time to a number and filter out everything, that is less or equal to `1200`:

```
var result = array.filter(function(e) {
    return +e.replace(':', '') > 1200;
});

console.log( result );  // ["12:30", "13:00"]
```

Comment: This solution is great, not only because it does what it means to, but it still works if the array isn't ordered.

Comment: Very extensive solution and I would like to thank you for that :D

Answer (score 2):

If the array is ordered, and the value `'12:00'` is always present then you can use the index and slice() like

```js
var array = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30'];
var newarray = array.slice(array.indexOf('10:00') + 1);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newarray))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If you are not sure about the presents of the value, then you need to iterate over the array and filer

```js
var array = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30'];
var newarray = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item > '10:00'
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newarray))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: The value '12:00' is not exactly always present, it's up to '12:00' but it should also filter all the values before if (e.g.) the highest value is '11:30'

Comment: So it should check up to a maximum of `12:00`, if that makes it more clear.

Comment: It's worth to note, that although string comparison will work in the current case, for a different time (especially when the format is different) it may go wrong, e.g. `'9:00' > '10:00' === true`.

Answer (score 1):

This method relies on time strings to always be formatted like this: `HH:mm`.

It will go through all items in the array and remove the elements that are less or equal to `'12:00'`.

```js
var times = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '12:30'];

for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    if (times[i] <= '12:00') {
        times.splice(i--, 1);
    }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(times);
// Running this code snippet will output ["12:30"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In which format your data is? If they are strings and Array is ordered, you could simply find index of element with "12:00" text and slice array from that position.

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('12:00') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `12.00` is present:

```
my_array = backend_array.slice(0, backend_array.index("12.00")+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `filter` function:

```js
var times = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30']
,   latestTime = breakUpTime('12:00')
,   result = ''
;
var newTimes = times.filter(function(time){
    var thisTime = breakUpTime(time);
    return thisTime['hour'] < latestTime['hour'] || (thisTime['hour'] == latestTime['hour'] && thisTime['minute'] <= latestTime['minute']);
});
function breakUpTime(time) {
    var parts = time.split(':');
    return {'hour' : parseInt(parts[0]), 'minute' : parseInt(parts[1])};
}
for(var time = 0; time < newTimes.length; time ++) {
    result += newTimes[time] + '<br/>';
}
document.write(result);
```